Using the ID3D11Texture2D pointer received from Unity in a native Rust plugin results in an error when calling a method
I am creating a Unity native plugin in Rust.
Since I needed to receive an ID3D11Texture2D in Rust, I decided to use the windows-rs crate version 0.56.0.
Unity Code
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class DesktopCapture : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [DllImport("texture2d_user", EntryPoint = "modify_texture")]
        static extern void ModifyTexture(IntPtr texptr);
    
        void Start()
        {
            var tex = Texture2D.normalTexture;
            ModifyTexture(tex.GetNativeTexturePtr());
        }
    }

Rust Code
    use windows::core::IUnknown;
    use windows::Win32::Graphics::Direct3D11::*;
    
    #[no_mangle]
    pub extern "C" fn modify_texture(texptr: *mut IUnknown) {
    
        let texture: *mut ID3D11Texture2D = texptr.cast::<ID3D11Texture2D>();
        let dimension: D3D11_RESOURCE_DIMENSION = unsafe { (*texture).GetType() };
    
        ()
    }

While the argument passing went smoothly, calling the GetType method on ID3D11Texture2D resulted in a Segmentation Fault error.
I would like to know how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.
To determine whether the issue lies with Unity or Rust, I created a native plugin in C++ and used it to create an ID3D11Texture2D. The methods were called without any problems, so I believe the issue is not with Unity.
Unity Editorlog
Received signal SIGSEGV
Obtained 26 stack frames
0x00007ffadcdc1020 (texture2d_user) texture2d_user::modify_texture (at C:/Users/sabro/source/testproject/texture2d_user/src/lib.rs:8)
0x000001ce154eb96a (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) DesktopCapture:ModifyTexture (intptr)
0x000001ce154eb573 (Mono JIT Code) DesktopCapture:Start () (at C:/Users/sabro/source/testproject/DesktopCapture/Assets/DesktopCapture.cs:17)
0x000001cdef27a488 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffadf74e274 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
0x00007ffadf68eb74 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3066)
0x00007ffadf68ed0c (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3113)
0x00007ff78895a824 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff788938944 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff78892715b (Unity) MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked
0x00007ff788927266 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked
0x00007ff7889212c2 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::DelayedStartCall
0x00007ff7883c2aa4 (Unity) DelayedCallManager::Update
0x00007ff7885f2c59 (Unity) `InitPlayerLoopCallbacks'::`2'::EarlyUpdateScriptRunDelayedStartupFrameRegistrator::Forward
0x00007ff7885d291c (Unity) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007ff7885d2a98 (Unity) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007ff7885d9375 (Unity) PlayerLoop
0x00007ff78959cd2f (Unity) PlayerLoopController::InternalUpdateScene
0x00007ff789594513 (Unity) PlayerLoopController::EnterPlayMode
0x00007ff7895a4887 (Unity) PlayerLoopController::SetIsPlaying
0x00007ff7895a7f50 (Unity) Application::TickTimer
0x00007ff789a1e51a (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff789a23d80 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff78ae07fee (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffbd02e7344 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffbd04226b1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


It looks like your .cast() is invoking <*mut T>::cast rather than <IUnknown as Interface>::cast. The former is just a straight pointer cast while the latter goes through QueryInterface. The giveaway is that Interface::cast returns a Result<T>, yet your code directly assigns the result to a *mut ID3D11Texture2D variable. Interface::cast is not even eligible to be called because it takes &self but you're calling .cast() on a raw pointer.
In the windows crate, an interface type like IUnknown is actually a pointer already: what we'd write IUnknown* in C or C++, we write just IUnknown in Rust. In your Rust functions that are called through FFI, your interface parameters should be typed *mut c_void, then you can cast them to an interface type using Interface::from_raw_borrowed. (Don't use Interface::from_raw here: the returned value will call Release() when it's dropped, but your function didn't do the corresponding AddRef() or QueryInterface().)
use std::ffi::c_void;
use windows::core::IUnknown;
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Direct3D11::*;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn modify_texture(texptr: *mut c_void) {
    let texptr = unsafe { IUnknown::from_raw_borrowed(&texptr).expect("got a null texture pointer") };
    let texture: ID3D11Texture2D = texptr.cast::<ID3D11Texture2D>().expect("object doesn't implement ID3D11Texture2D");
    let dimension: D3D11_RESOURCE_DIMENSION = unsafe { texture.GetType() };
}

